# Como dar o "espaçamento" na área onde se escreve o texto

Tags: css, html5

Olá, gostaria de alterar o posicionamento do | ao selecionar o textbox, tenho um esboço e o que estou tentando fazer não fica ajustado igual a 2° imagem. Há alguma propriedade que faça isso? Agradecido, To batendo a cabeça faz tempo nisso ..

Assim é como o " | " está, praticamente colado com o TextBox
[image]

Assim como quero que o  " | " fique assim ao selecionar o textbox e alinhado com o placeholder

Obs: Eu já alterei o placeholder da seguinte maneira:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #bbbbbb;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tira o `padding` da pseudo-classe do `placeholder` e coloca direto no `input`. Uma vez que vc coloca o `padding` no `input` ele já posiciona o marcador no lugar correto e tb "empurra" o `placeholder` pro lugar correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="meu placeholder">
```

Comment: Deu certo! Só tive que alterar o width do textbox pra ficar parelho com o botão, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado, até engraçado o quanto é simples pra resolver esse problema :P

Comment: @Dreidel se a resposta ajudou, marca como solução para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @Dreidel sim e mais facil do que parecia né rss, se vc acha que a resposta resolveu o problema vc pode considerar marca-la nesse ícon ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta, Se no futuro aparecer outra resposte que vc julque mais adequada vc pode mudar a aceitação para a outra resposta se achar justificável

Comment: @samuelrvg valeu a força 